# continue job for each iteration after success return jQuery ajax and each

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

In php I know that each function can return true/false. JavaScript does the same, how can a jQuery `$.each` iteration be operated by this true/false? I mean how can I tell to the iteration to stay until it get a response?

Right now I'm using the function `setTimeout()` in jQuery, but I want to replace with the true/false response and go to next iteration, is there a way?

My script is:

```
$(document).on( "click", '#sync',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sync').prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"./post/dataUrl",    
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    console.log('Success, lets start the sync !');

                    $.each(data.data, function(i,item){
                        setTimeout(function() {
                            syncData(item.product_id);

                            var percentage = Math.ceil((i/data.total)*1000)/10;
                            $('#test').html('<div class="note note-success"><p>The sync is working... '+percentage+'% '+i+'/'+data.total+' <code>'+item.product_id+'</code></p></div>')

                            if(i == data.total - 1){
                                $('#sync').prop('disabled', false);
                                $('#test').empty();
                            }
                        }, i * 500); //So, in practic it runs after each 500ms, how can i replace this by standing on the response of syncData(product_id) ?
                    });
                    return false;
                }
            }
    });
});

function syncData(product_id){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"./post/dataSave",    
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    return true;
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really keep the each loop iterations from running immediately after each other. It sounds more like you want a callback to trigger the next item. I haven't tested this code myself but it should give you a hint of how to do it. For every completed syncData it will sync the next item.

```
$(document).on( "click", '#sync',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#sync').prop('disabled', true);
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"./post/dataUrl",    
            data: {},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    console.log('Success, lets start the sync !');
                    function syncItem(i) {
                        var percentage = Math.ceil((i/data.total)*1000)/10;
                        $('#test').html('<div class="note note-success"><p>The sync is working... '+percentage+'% '+i+'/'+data.total+' <code>'+item.product_id+'</code></p></div>')
                        if (i == data.total) {
                            $('#sync').prop('disabled', false);
                            $('#test').empty();
                        } else {
                            var item = data.data[i];
                            syncData(item.product_id, function () {
                                // Here we make the next item sync
                                syncItem(i + 1);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (data.total > 0) {
                        syncItem(0);
                    } else {
                        // handle empty data case
                    }
                }
            }
    });
});

function syncData(product_id, callback){
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:"./post/dataSave",    
            data: {product_id: product_id},
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                if(data.status == 'success'){
                    callback();
                }
            }
    });
}
```

Comment: Well, it sound promising, but the product_id is coming from an array, and that's because the $.each iteration, to send each product_id to the function and sync it, but in this scenario i can't see how can i handle the array loop,

Comment: From what I understood data.data had this structure: [{product_id: 123}, {product_id: 456}, ...]. If that's not the case, could you perhaps post an example of how it looks, in your question?

Comment: Hey @andrrs, sorry for the delay, this is the json data returned: `{"status":"success","total":3, "data":[{"product_id":"37780"},{"product_id":"37451"},{"product_id":"37713"}] }`

Comment: @anddrs, i have tested your script and is fine, the only issue is that it doesn't go to the 100% for example on 3 items, it will return that has finish at the 2 loop.

Comment: What i mean is that, it send only 2 items to syncData not all 3 items :), Thx

Comment: @ndAR No worries. Oh, yeah the "data.total - 1" looks weird. Corrected now.

Comment: That's it ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

Try using [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue) , [`$.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map)

```
$({}).queue("ajax",
    $.map(data.data, function(item, i) {
      return function(next) {
        setTimeout(function() {

          var percentage = Math.ceil((i / data.total) * 1000) / 10;
          $('#test').html('<div class="note note-success">'
            + '<p>The sync is working... ' 
            + percentage + '% ' 
            + i + '/' + data.total + ' <code>' 
            + item.product_id + '</code></p></div>'
          );

          if (i == data.total - 1) {
            $('#sync').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#test').empty();
          }
          // So, in practic it runs after each 500ms,
          // how can i replace this by standing on the response of 
          // syncData(product_id) ?
          syncData(item.product_id).then(next)
        }, i * 500); 
      }
    })
).dequeue("ajax");
```